# Select a text element for styling

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this situation:

```html
    <a href="...">
      <span>
         <svg>...</svg>
         A label
      </span>
    </a>
```

How can I select the `"A label"` text element (being the second child of the span element) in order to style it?

Is is possible somehow?

Comment: is label a `<label>` or is it just text that says "Label"? think about that

Comment: @soulshined: just a simple text :)

Comment: simply style the span element since it's the only text there

Comment: @TemaniAfif there is a <svg> tag also :)

Comment: it's not a text, so if you will apply coloration, font, etc it won't get affected

Comment: @TemaniAfif I want to apply: display: none :D

Comment: so you need to say this in the question because display:none isn't a visual style ... see the duplicate for a solution

Answer (score 2):

Set styles for the span element, and unset for its children:

```css
.aSpan{
   color: red;
}

.aSpan > *{
   color: initial;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <span class="aSpan">
       <div>Not this</div>
         This
      </span>
</a>
```